# Handling application event of a managed packaged lightning component in my code

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning

I have installed a lightning component from a managed package, in which an application event is being fired on the click of an button. Now I want to handle that event in my another component  which I am working on.

my name space is **om_ltng** . My event name is **showResultEvent**

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION"   >
  <aura:attribute name="search_value" type="String"/>
  <aura:attribute name="search_name" type="String"/>
</aura:event>
```

This event is defined in the managed package. So in my method I am handling it like this.

```
  <aura:handler event="om_ltng:showResultEvent" action="{!c.getValueFromApplicationEvent}"/>
```

but it is showing error something like this **Failed to save undefined: No EVENT named showResultEvent found: Source**. 
Thoughts plz.

Answer (score 0):

Are you registering your application event using this syntax?

```
 <aura:registerEvent type="om_ltng:showResultEvent"...
```

It can be found in the docs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/namespace_using_reference.htm#namespace_using_reference)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I found the fix for my problem. I was missing access="global" in the declaration and in the registration of event.